# Vue router changes URL, but not content of page for updated params

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vue-router

I have a news page with a list of articles (pulled from Firebase). Beside each article is a list of topic tags. When a user clicks on a tag, they're taken to a `Tag.vue` page listing only articles related to that tag using an `ArticlesList` component. This part is successful, however, when another tag is clicked while on `Tag.vue`, the router correctly changes the URL, but the content remains static.

Upon reading the [official Vue documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes) and similar questions here, I understand that `watch` or `beforeRouteUpdate` can be used to reload the content, but I'm not sure what to put inside either one to achieve this. I've attempted variations of `this.$router.push`, which has resulted in nothing or infinite redirects.

My code is below, with the pertinent part between comments.

**Router links to tag pages**

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'Tag', params: { tagURL: tag } }">{{tag}}</router-link>
```

**index.js**

```
  {
    path: '/news/tag/:tagURL',
    name: 'Tag',
    component: Tag,
    props: true
  }
```

**Tag.vue**

```
<template>
    <ArticlesList :dbQuery="dbQuery" :dbLimit="dbLimit"/>
</template>

<script>
    import ArticlesList from '@/components/ArticlesList'
    import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

    export default {
        props: {
            tagURL: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        },
        components: { ArticlesList },
        setup(props) {
            const router = useRouter()

            const dbQuery = ['tags', 'array-contains', props.tagURL]
            const dbLimit = 10

            return { dbLimit, dbQuery, router }
        },

        //**************************************************
        // use watch? $route or "$route.params"?
        watch: {

            $route(to, from) {
                 // what goes in here to reload the content?
            }

            "$route.params": function(params) {
                 // what goes in here to reload the content?
             }
         },

        // or is beforeRouteUpdate better?
        beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
            // what goes in here to reload the content?
        },
        //**************************************************

    name: 'Tag'
    }
</script>
```

*Edit (5/17/21):* Attempted `<ArticlesView :articleQuery="articleQuery" :articleLimit="articleLimit" :key="$route.fullPath"/>` to no avail. The component flashes, as if it's updating, but then displays the same content as before.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Try adding a `:key` so that when the tag changes your element that contains the articles reloads. https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/key-attribute.html#overview

Comment: Thanks, @db2. I tried `<ArticlesView :articleQuery="articleQuery" :articleLimit="articleLimit" :key="$route.fullPath"/>`, which flashes the component showing the articles, but doesn't reload the new tag's content. Should I use something else for the key?

Comment: are the props values inside ArticleView  updated?? Check from devtools